# Juxtaposing three background photos next to each other in jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, col

I have the following code for putting three background photo next to each other. I am not sure why nothing is shown in the jumbotron. Can you please hint me to figure what are the possible causes?

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style=" margin-top: 90px; ">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-y-3">

        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-3" style=" background: url('./assets/img/glass.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain ">

        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="background: url('./assets/img/mhacks.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size:contain ">

        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-3" style="background: url('./assets/img/rift.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain ">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you don't have any content inside divs. Add some content inside them and backgrounds will be visible.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Fgqh5jn

Comment: Just for Information. When you have same number of columns in all breakpoints like `class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-3"` then only `class="col-sm-3"` will be enough because Bootstrap is mobile first. Styles of `sm` will also be applied at `md` and `lg` resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have any content inside divs,if you want only image in divs, you can do like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style=" margin-top: 90px; ">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-y-3">

        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <img src="./assets/img/glass.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <img src="./assets/img/mhacks.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <img src="./assets/img/rift.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set height for your three divs. When using **background**, you need to have a height set for the div that you're giving a background to.